# Restore Backup Access Denied

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, database-restore

I'm trying to restore a backup from a `.bak` file to a local database server and keep getting the error message.

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   Cannot open backup device 'C:\Clients\SQLitis\jMKZ.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
>   RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3201)

No idea where to even start troubleshooting this. I'm on an administrator account and have full privileges so there shouldn't be anything to deny me doing this but I'm still getting the error message.

Comment: @casperOne, how can that other question be a duplicate of this one when they don't even have the same error message?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sounds like the service account that SQL Server runs under does not have permission to folder C:\Clients\SQLitis.

When SQL Server was installed, it hopefully was set up to use a domain user account (the "service account") that is NOT an administrator on the machine. As such, the SQL Server installer only grants permissions to the folders the SQL Server setup creates.

Comment: I had to grand permissions to Service Account on Folder as well as the file. Many Thanks!

Comment: Great! To allow service account to access the file i right clicked the folder, on properties/security i added "everyone". AFter that i could restore.

Comment: For everyone having issues with LOG SHIPPING and already gave permissions to the folder to the SQL Server Agent User in order to allow it to copy the backup files to the location - that's not enough, the SQL Server DB Engine Service Account needs the permissions as well. That's the trap I just climbed out :)

Comment: If that's the case, then why not just change the mode back to mixed so you can use a domain account that's a local admin as well? Steps on that can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode#to-change-security-authentication-mode

Answer (score 8):

You need to give permission to that folder to the user account that SQL Server acts as.  In my case it was **NT Service\MSSQLSERVER**

You can find/change the SQL Server user in **SQL Server Configuration Manager**.  Here's a link that shows how:

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ShawnHarrison/ssis/2134/access-denied-during-database-backup

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little hacky, but I solved the issue by copying the .bak file into the designated backup folder. That way I didn't have to change any permissions.